# send data with header in python

Tags: python, http

i have a web site : http://example.com/request.aspx

i want to send this data :

```
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24TimerLoad&__VIEWSTATE=zQYAx7DovdNMbvvUn4ED%2F7coUdhi1CU2sov8F9JM0GbcNXbxh8RjwucELnjFfh65WAcCTdZ57Cf77j%2BIAcXzHIi5EaqxCIpc2T%2FD883HtiVN2k5FOPnudAhI18EQ0RN%2BoH%2F5O5ozSdudupQeZaQvB1GJvLpbD6IAhhZtHU1T5FTGzV2dI3bCa9592OE8Gs1CO6udTW8CbzL9sKsHdGjojoaxQYycbvtE5RMtxUiE1glT34RJtABZkh%2Fo4g6JlLd8yVZVI8ISfH8nVqXljzYVx7qvqyT%2BmF5oY5I%2Fwoums%2BDBKDce1hGBcMoXddIvMabPgeGm6CKSozoHm1gykCAFJ5m2L2Cg83PhY4gtpFOwM9G2a2DoqC7qKgXIYAha%2B7zg2oBAYysngBOS%2BLOkAP59pO4PtttP2ja1L5HO4k5Ef%2B47vb%2B2Nz0s%2B%2FAmU%2Fbpe%2Br9gnJcjZfBYSNFDmUoNIK5spIn%2BoQUILYEdKH2imuq1lZqQ0yu%2FsxcNfu6FXweiXxxuPkiLwdOTQw3uv%2F3P082%2Fmunm9La%2ByZG0qO42gMfuRzMnKzb%2BOD8bZkXy%2B%2FZz597dDjaoH0REaOidVhEtF76q6CgDG7uYil07qJGLl4iv5dyFadHmMNr4ezOpxq%2BsXlp8HUHJ%2BJMyd2fEgphYZInOWk80yhWIbhaUorxmmShJOmq9Nfg3yOMTuHhtiGblw%2BxLwV5V5ONohCJ0W4vgXoSOHvVmjMHE24tFtyuZnog%2F%2FbWtWEU%2F5cXcnclEJT8HgtRKgabqSpGO6CbB%2BQB0PwL%2FgA8KbQjrXU%2BNQ0yX%2B2Su5ZFjJJPVuOtS2JsCOKHcicYuo9KSL4FUAH0iJR1pmcTdKur1TJTw5k2V7EVAQ0Jz6HiLIBq%2BE3Y5%2BgP41m5lj4%2BTipVZcExJJloDZOYUQU49yECIgYaCzpQXaBaiNJ%2BHUpeCGb%2F9Vpd49cWOs4wcK%2Bvo0Mp8KIRbk8DLP%2FDG0eCkk5yTod57Em5WLrZHhhfLywnqaGtWMGC%2FKFP39cdd%2BHwr2Mewoqdie4MrwohukeuvmRzApMWHhTSLWhJi4SwZbW%2FLRwA5ZMMWnqqMEB2N158evHfe5eRPeLB3sGs7KnrB2ApfPTbLhm5s%2FoddvZqFtVD2oLeY0f4d4HnPqeAsOlY7%2FFBqWjmGj8gaORMV8xKCKvaUaKDxyhgiKRqgSjawejhtuzfkoaXV7qWeZ6j4NXH8pHH%2FxYnylCJ5yf0xallrljtadcHHsDqgTTG8GM6wpniv%2FGYaYu0nWLJDnfMAO4jlaskAis2EhlIReaQbV13C1Z1TTL1vwGF7p9wnIsjkYQBVg9Vu3vU5CgmOLfDegDC%2BrFLTH9k13oOzLOE0Rizrn04obdO71sUrvFjI8KKx008J83hk9yBvGPmHQqrm1SnPdTbj%2BUZm0EPexg1fM0sRQg8azEDGWgh93G%2Be%2B7dKYb061qIoKj8Ac8Hlm30XT77YiY1VIGjg6pMD%2FuFQp1f6UjVU6M1uSO2ZaB6FZDhN75J2WkT31PJ3WJOjuFjM3e%2FVZV%2FseFkUNvtI69mtCZv3L1fWMGsyO4IajD1B%2FMnpEf5MKejBfjZc9IU3L4Qr9PbfwuX5FJAkR0TIJj3MoV2v6oFiD6wxpx0ARKhrVMn1%2FAQxGAB&__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=&
```

with this headers:

```
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130917 Firefox/17.0 Iceweasel/17.0.9
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
```

to that page, and get the results. how can i do it?

thanks.

Comment: Please try to do minimal research before you post a question.